# Android UDP can't send or recive

Tags: android, sockets, udp

I'm trying to implement a UDP server and client without succes.
For the problem dissection I'll only write about the client. I have a button that launch the next UDP client:

```
int UDP_SERVER_PORT = 45455;
private final static int MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN = 4096;

public void runUdpClient()  {

    String udpMsg = "hello world from UDP client ";
    //  DatagramSocket ds = null;

    try {

        DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.36"); //127.0.0.1
        DatagramPacket dp;
        dp = new DatagramPacket(udpMsg.getBytes(), udpMsg.length(), serverAddr, UDP_SERVER_PORT);
        Log.v("NEXT", udpMsg);
        ds.send(dp);
        ds.close();

    } catch (SocketException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } 

}
```

In my manifest I give the next permissions:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bolet.simpleudpsenderreceiver" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"> </uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

In my UDP server, tested long time ago, in my laptop, I never recive anything. The phone is not an emulated phone, and is connected at the same network than me. And my udp server is listening in my port.

I don't found anything wrong!!! What could be?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked that the IP is correct?
Everything seems to be ok. If no exception is thrown check the IP and check that the port is the correct too or change it.

Comment: All is Ok!! This is what I can't understand :(, Anyway rechecking

Comment: Definitely all is Ok and I can't found why I can't send this UDP... Also I can send UDP between laptops but never phone-laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a code that works properly. 
Executing the sender as async task:

MsgSender.java

```
class MsgSender extends AsyncTask<HashMap, Integer, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(HashMap... params) {
    //Retrieve params
    HashMap<String, Object> p = params[0];
    String testServer = (String) p.get("ip");
    String udpMsg = (String)  p.get("msg");
    Integer port = (int) p.get("port");

    InetAddress serverAddr = null;
    DatagramSocket ds = null;
    DatagramPacket dp = null;
    /*
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }*/

    try {
        serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(testServer);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        ds = new DatagramSocket();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    dp = new DatagramPacket(udpMsg.getBytes(), udpMsg.length(), serverAddr, port);

    try {
        ds.send(dp);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ds.close();
    return null;
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
int UDP_SERVER_PORT = 45455;
int MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN = 4096;
//String testServer = "192.168.1.39"; //127.0.0.1
String testServer = "10.0.2.2";
String udpMsg = "HELLO!\r\n\0";
int port = 45455;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final EditText ipView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipValue);
final EditText msgView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textValue);
final EditText portView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.portValue);
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click
        testServer = ipView.getText().toString();
        udpMsg = msgView.getText().toString()+"\r\n\0";
        port = Integer.parseInt( portView.getText().toString() );

        HashMap<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("ip", testServer);
        params.put("msg", udpMsg);
        params.put("port", port);
        new MsgSender().execute(params);

    }
});
```

}

Thanks to nyu's help fr that!

Comment: ... the difference between this and your original code being what? That is, what is the actual answer here?

Comment: I had the same issue and the solution really is as simple as that. Thanks for this!